# Selecionar localização a partir do estado

Tags: mysql, sql

Tenho a seguinte estrutura (fictícia)

**Tabela estado:**

```
id | name | status
```

**Tabela localização:**

```
id | title | estado_id
```

No meu front-end eu tenho uma `navbar` que vai listar os estados e em cada estado as localidades.

Estou usando a seguinte *query*

```
SELECT estado.name, localizacao.title
FROM estado
INNER JOIN localizacao ON estado.id = localizaçao.estado_id
```

Funciona legal, o problema é que ele retorna o estado de acordo com a quantidade de localização.

Segue exemplo do retorno

```
name  | title 
EUA   | cidade
EUA   | cidade
USA.  | cidade
```

Eu não quero que o *EUA* repita.

Resolvi temporariamente usando duas queries separada.

Comment: Coloca um exemplo, em forma de tabela, de como você quer que retorne. Eu não entendi direito.

Comment: Eu tenho um div de categorias e nessas categorias são listadas as informações. Na query que mostrei ele trás as categorias repetidas, não quero que repita. Seria algo como um array, $category = array("categoria1"=>array("1","2")); esse categoria1 não pode repetir.

Comment: Nesse exemplo que você deu, esses dois registros com name=EUA, o campo _title_ terá o mesmo valor nos dois registros?

Comment: Só que o sql devolve tudo em tabela. Os dados que você quer estão aí. Você precisa dar um loop neles pelo php e transformar na estrutura de arrays que você quer. E essa estrutura você usa para gerar o html.

Comment: O title pode ser diferente. Name é o estado e title a cidade. Seria como um grupo, se eu tenho 40 cidades em SP, eu quero que me retorne as cidades como conjunto de SP e não uma cidade pro mesmo estado 40 vezes. A única lógica que encontrei foi em query separada.

Comment: Ou você faz query separada, ou faz essa com join e transforma depois na estrutura que quer. O sql não trabalha com estruturas aninhadas, somente dados tabulares.

Comment: Utilize [JSON](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json.html) do MySQL para retornar apenas o nome e um JSON Array com os "titles".

Comment: @bfvaretto exatamente isso, eu sinto como se fosse uma gambiarra, o caminho é tratar no PHP, achei que houvesse outro meio. Obrigado.

Comment: Nessa consulta que mostrou, sempre vai trazer os estados repetidos, pode cada estado pode ter várias localizações. Sendo assim, teu problema é na sula tela. Você será obrigado a ter duas consultas. A primeira consulta vai trazer todos os estados, ao selecionar o estado faz a consulta com o ID do estado retornando as cidades que pertencem a esse estado.